# Google GetDistance function not working properly

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I am trying to filter search results by their distance to a given position in the search conditions. Each offer has its own position, including (german) zip Code and the City that belongs to it. The search condition includes the same principle.
So in the End, there is the position of the searcher, and multiple positions of the offers.
In addition, all offers have a radius, in which they can operate.
Then I want to filter out all offers, that have a higher distance to the searchers position, than their operation radius.
I have used this PHP-Code:

```
$position = $_GET['position']!='' ? $_GET['position'] : '';
```

To get the position from the searcher out of my URL.

```
$Results = $database->SearchResults('Conditions of the database Query');
```

which builds a Query out of the information in the URL and searches my database.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Results)) {
    echo $functions->GetDistance($position, $row[1], "K")."<br>";
}
```

This while loop is supposed to show me the distance of each offer to the postition of the searcher

```
function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
        //Change address format
        $formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
        $formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

        //Send request and receive json data
        $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
        $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
        $geocodeTo = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false');
        $outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

        //Get latitude and longitude from geo data
        $latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        $latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        //Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
        $theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);
        if ($unit == "K") {
            return ($miles * 1.609344).' km';
        }
        else if ($unit == "N") {
            return ($miles * 0.8684).' nm';
        }
        else {
            return $miles.' mi';
        }
    }
```

And this is the function, I found in this forum to get distances between two addresses.
It works most of the time and I get the right distances, for example: 77.4640983104 km.
But every two or three runs, I get this error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

and

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0

in the "Get latitude and longitude from geo data" section and a wrong distance of 0 km as the output.
I really don't know which mistake I am doing, but I hope someone can explain to me, what should be changed, or wether the whole thing is approached in a wrong way.
Thank You very much in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: You need to verify that `file_get_contents` didn't encounter an error.

Comment: This does not delete the error.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

The function does work, if the Google API-Key is added to the URL.
Seems like the function I found is from the time before using Maps got commercialized.